# Mi web abre una ventana emergente de una web externa

Tags: php, html

me he estado dando cuenta que mi web la primera vez que entras en el día o cuando pasan muchas horas de que no entras al hacer click en algun link de la web (cualquiera) te redirecciona y te abre una página emergente y luego se cierra rápido, recién fuí capaz de copiar el vínculo antes de que se cerrara  es este (https://log.videocampaign.co/ContinueV/?vid=HtM80f4ZDFM&jid=4387454&cc=)

¿Porque puede ser que pase esto? En local host no pasa

Yo creo que es por mi proveedor de hosting o mi proveedor de dominio .com

en los htaccess tengo esto, nada más
(este código teóricamente lo que hace es redireccionar de http a https)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

Agradezco su tiempo!

Modif: agrego un video de que es lo que pasa

Estos son los 2 vínculos que se ven en el video

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RyWkBylRCKY

No uso wordpress (vi algo relacionado con eso y aparentemente es un virus de wordpress y únicamente me pasa con mi web)

Lo que yo creo que puede ser es que tengo un dominio con godaddy y la seguridad es 'básica', no sé si será eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que tienes un problema relacionado a:

1.- Tu navegador, puede que tengas instalado algun adware, haz un chequeo de seguridad con un BUEN antivirus y elimina todo el adware que tengas en tu maquina (para saber si solo es tu maquina, abre tu sitio desde alguna otra maquina o con algun otro navegador por ejemplo con [LYNX](https://lynx.browser.org/))

2.- Tu sitio fue hackeado, checa todos los scripts en el servidor y borra lo que no conozcas o haz una instalacion limpia (borra todo del servidor y vuelve a subir tu codigo) OjO: es posible que solo hayan añadido una linea de codigo en algun script asi que busca ampliamente.

Espero que te sirva la informacion.